# Identifying distribution of random variable given mgf

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, moment-generating-functions

I have the following question, and am not too sure even where to start to solve this one! So any help or tips would be so much appreciated!

“A random variable Y has moment generating function $M_Y(t) = \lambda / (\lambda - t).$ Identify that distribution of Y. 
A random variable U has moment generating function $M_U(t)= \lambda / (\lambda +t)$. How is the random variable U related to Y? "

Thankyou in advance!!!

Comment: Well the most common thing to do is to check if any of the known Moment Generating Functions have **exactly** the same form as $M_Y(t) = \lambda / (\lambda - t).$. We can check and it turns out that the Exponential distribution with parameter $\frac 1{\lambda}$ is the distribution of Y.

Comment: As for $U$, it is almost the same, perhaps look at the first and second moments by using $M_U(t)=$. Hint: What values does an exponential distribution take at different values of t?